# Get the currently selected item from a pull down list in concrete5

Tags: drop-down-menu, concrete5

I'm trying to solve a problem using concrete5
The user wants a block to be able to display information on a book selected from a database
everything is in place up to the selection menu I can populate the drop down list with the titles in the database but when a book is selected the block simply displays the index value of the selection menu's options array.

For example if the array looked something like

0 => Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, 
1 => Game of Thrones

and the user selects Harry Potter from the list the block simply displays "0" as the given title. I'm reasonably sure i can fix this by means of using a function to assign the correct values by querying the database. but I can't seem to get the selected item from the selection menu only it's array index value.

any thoughts?

code is as follows

add.php

```
    <?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied.")) ?>
<?php $titles = $controller -> getTitles() ?>
<div class="ccm-ui">
    <?php echo $form->select('bookselect', $titles, 1, array('style' => 'width: auto;')) ?>

</div>
```

I tried using `$ title = $this -> $_REQUEST['bookselect'];` but it didn't work and now some hours later I'm at a loss

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already populating the list of titles from a controller function, you can simply re-use that for the "view" of your block. So in your block controller, find the `view()` function (or add it if it's not already there), and do this:

```
$titles = $this->getTitles();
$this->set('title', $titles[$bookselect]);
```

Now in your block's view template, you will have the `$title` variable available to echo, and it will contain the name of the book.

Comment: No luck there I'm afraid nothing is being posted to the database. When I execute the add script and make a selection and then run a select all query on the block instance table I get null across the board (primary key notwithstanding)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your situation is. Perhaps if you provide the actual code from your block's controller.php, add.php, edit.php, and view.php files it would be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

A HTML Select element only passes its array index (or the value attribute) it won't ever send you the value, that's just not the way HTML works.

You have a couple of options.

1. Look up value from Index in database.
2. Change index to include value eg ()

Comment: so the value wasn't the solution then? However I'm now populating the select box with an array which uses the row's unique identifier as the key and the title column as the value. but when I click add the database still gets null values appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the select box is as follows,

```
$form->select($name, $options, $selectedValue, $tagAttributes);
```

in your example,

```
$form->select('bookselect', $titles, 1, array('style' => 'width: auto;'))
```

This should select Game of thrones as the selected book, (assuming the value being used is an the key of the array), you could try passing the options as an associative array

```
array(
'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire'=>'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire',
'Game of Thrones'=>'Game of Thrones'
)
```

That way, the values passed would be values and passing back in the title should help select the option.

```
$form->select('bookselect', $titles, $title, array('style' => 'width: auto;'))
```

I have not tested this so some sanitation of the title may be required to use it as a key.